# how to publish mqtt message with retained true in paho on android

Tags: java, android, mqtt, paho

I am using Paho java client library for my on android App. Code provided below.

```
MqttAndroidClient client_Panic = new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), serverURL, CLIENT_ID);
    try {
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1);
        options.setCleanSession(false);
        options.setKeepAliveInterval(90);
        options.setConnectionTimeout(100);
        IMqttToken token = client_Panic.connect(options);

            //Few callbacks

       } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And publishing messages, when required

```
    String msg = "messages";
    MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage();
    message.setPayload(msg.getBytes());
    try {
        client_Panic.publish(topic, message);
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It is working fine, but somehow incomplete. What I need is, whenever other client subscribed to same topic, should get the last retained message, which publisher might had published earlier.

For that I searched on their documentation, I got

```
protected void setWill(String topic,
                   MqttMessage msg,
                   int qos,
                   boolean retained)
```

So setWill as per documentation have the option to enable the retained option. So I tried with

```
        options.setConnectionTimeout(100);
        options.setWill(topic,null,2,true); // This place I added
        IMqttToken token = client_Panic.connect(options);
```

But got error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions.validateWill` on the line containing `options.setWill`.

Is setWill is the correct method for enabling `retained true` on android, if yes then what parameters need to be provided or else their is any other method for enabling it on android? TIA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Will is a very specific message that is only published if the client disconnects uncleanly from the broker (e.g. network drops).

You can not set a `null` message as the Will message which is what the error is about.

The retained state is specific to a given message so you do not set it globally, it is set on each message. To mark a message as retained when you just call the `setRetained(boolean)` e.g.

```
String msg = "messages";
MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage();
message.setRetained(true);
message.setPayload(msg.getBytes());
try {
    client_Panic.publish(topic, message);
} catch (MqttException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @hardillb hold on, you should be able to set the will as a null message, assuming that means a zero length message.

Comment: @ralight, that would be a Message object with a zero length byte array, this is a null Message object.